# Definitions type for pulumi API management api schema resource

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, pulumi

APISchema resource from pulumi azure native provider has a definition property that should have types for the API, I'm struggling to find a documentation explaining how to set this property on pulumi and what types are accepted, setting the property to a string works has this error: "ApiSchema resource 'schema' has a problem: 'definitions' should be of type '' but got a string".

What should be assigned to definition property to populate azure api management definitions list?

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: I'm using C#, with the following Pulumi versions as well

Pulumi: 3.0.0
Pulumi.AzureNative: 1.1.0

Comment: I think you need to use dictionaries, similar to this https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi-azure-native/issues/563#issuecomment-768389539 You may have to use inline dictionaries and lists for multi-level objects, which is kind of ugly but that's how untyped objects are currently handled.

Comment: I changed the definition to use inline dictionary as you mentioned, pulumi validation is successful, only thing azure API now fails with error: Code="Failed" Message="The async operation failed."

Comment: Please file an issue on github with a repro snippet and we'll take a look